# Apache webserver with AJP connection to Tomcat - empty TLS attributes in request object

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy, tls1.2, ajp

We are using an Apache (2.4.41) webserver as reverse proxy for a tomcat (8.5), that runs a self implemented load-balancer.
The Apache webserver does the front end TLS stuff and talks to tomcat over AJP (mod_proxy_ajp). Within our load-balancer, we use request.getAttributeNames() to evaluate request attributes. For some time now, empty request attributes with following keys appear:

- org.apache.tomcat.util.net.secure_protocol_version
- javax.servlet.request.key_size
- javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite
- javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id

I read documentation and source code but can't figure out, why these empty attributes still exist within the request. According to the javadoc of getAttributeNames() in a tomcat [request](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java), most of the TLS specific attributes should not be fetched by this method:

```
/**
 * Return the names of all request attributes for this Request, or an
 * empty <code>Enumeration</code> if there are none. Note that the attribute
 * names returned will only be those for the attributes set via
 * {@link #setAttribute(String, Object)}. Tomcat internal attributes will
 * not be included although they are accessible via
 * {@link #getAttribute(String)}. The Tomcat internal attributes include:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link Globals#DISPATCHER_TYPE_ATTR}</li>
 * <li>{@link Globals#DISPATCHER_REQUEST_PATH_ATTR}</li>
 * <li>{@link Globals#ASYNC_SUPPORTED_ATTR}</li>
 * <li>{@link Globals#CERTIFICATES_ATTR} (SSL connections only)</li>
 * <li>{@link Globals#CIPHER_SUITE_ATTR} (SSL connections only)</li>
 * <li>{@link Globals#KEY_SIZE_ATTR} (SSL connections only)</li>
 * <li>{@link Globals#SSL_SESSION_ID_ATTR} (SSL connections only)</li>
 * <li>{@link Globals#SSL_SESSION_MGR_ATTR} (SSL connections only)</li>
 * <li>{@link Globals#PARAMETER_PARSE_FAILED_ATTR}</li>
 * </ul>
 * The underlying connector may also expose request attributes. These all
 * have names starting with "org.apache.tomcat" and include:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link Globals#SENDFILE_SUPPORTED_ATTR}</li>
 * </ul>
 * Connector implementations may return some, all or none of these
 * attributes and may also support additional attributes.
 *
 * @return the attribute names enumeration
 */
 @Override
 public Enumeration<String> getAttributeNames() {
```

Maybe some can shed some light on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc is not entirely correct: as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#L869) you cite, `getAttributeNames` does not list these internal attributes **unless** you already called `getAttribute` for one of them:

```java
        if (!sslAttributesParsed && TLSUtil.isTLSRequestAttribute(name)) {
            coyoteRequest.action(ActionCode.REQ_SSL_ATTRIBUTE, coyoteRequest);
            attr = coyoteRequest.getAttribute(Globals.CERTIFICATES_ATTR);
            if (attr != null) {
                attributes.put(Globals.CERTIFICATES_ATTR, attr);
            }
            attr = coyoteRequest.getAttribute(Globals.CIPHER_SUITE_ATTR);
            if (attr != null) {
                attributes.put(Globals.CIPHER_SUITE_ATTR, attr);
            }
            ...
```